# Show process status using AJAX and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have a method in my controller that kicks of a job on the server. I'll use a Ajax call (jQuery) to start this via a link on the page. This can take a while and I need to show some status on the page. I don't necessarily need "26% done ..." but more a status showing "working" or "done".

How do a get jQuery to continuously pull for the status of the job? Or should it be solved differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some sort of state to hold the status of the task which both the task and Javascript can Access.  For example Server Cache.  Say you use a key of TaskComplete.

Kick off your task with javascript through AJAX

While Your Task Is Running

Task updates Server Cache Item

End While

***Parallel***

Use Javascript to poll the cache for a value

Kick off your task with javascript through AJAX

While Ajax Response Not Task Complete

wait 2 seconds

Call a javascript function through ajax again to read the value of the Server Cache Item

Execute relevant task based on its value

An Article you may find useful is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163393.aspx

Comment: OK. Good that's what i thought. But how do I do this "loop"/"timer" in jQuery to keep pulling for status?

Comment: Use: setTimeout(your_callback, timeout_in_ms);

Comment: Yes, using the setTimeout though I find it better to use the following syntax

var t = setInterval(function(){//execute your function here},milliseconds);

When finished

clearInterval(t);

Comment: Or find a Jquery Timer Plugin.  Both would be sufficient.  Hope this helps :-)